# Bootstrap Tour Select First Child Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have added bootstrap tour to a dynamically created page which in one place uses a loop to generate a list.

This obviously generates a selector for each element in the loop - in my case a data attribute.

The problem is that when a tour element has multiple instances the tour popup shows on all elements in the list. I have tried the following but it does not seem to work ......

```
....
{
    element: '*[data-bootstrap_tour="tour-1-1"]:first-child',
    placement: "bottom",
    title: "My Title",
    content: "My Content blah blah blah"
}
....
```

This still selects all elements with the data attribute `tour-1-1`

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate your issue, it's bit confusing. Also please provide JS Fiddle code for the same.

Comment: You are confusing `:first-child` and `:first`.

Comment: @RoToRa hit the nail on the head. Thanks - you should put this as the answer